# Use Django Queryset filter API on in-memory list of Model instances?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is it possible to re-use the Django Queryset API when I've already retrieved a list of objects? i.e.

```
foos = list(Foo.objects.filter(color="red"))
# below doesn't work, but is what I'd like to reproduce
large_foos = foos.filter(size="large")
small_foos = foos.filter(size="small")
```

I can of course iterate through my `foos` list, but it'd look cleaner to reuse the API, especially if filtering multiple attributes.

Use case(s) for why I want to filter in-memory:

- I want to minimize number of db queries
- the return set of `foos` is small and more efficient to filter in-memory
- `color` is indexed but `size` is not
- `size` has high cardinality

Comment: What do you mean by *reusing*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Some handy util function or official API that allows me to specify `foos.fn(attr1="a", attr2="b")` and get the filtered list back based on attribute. Just equality will be fine, but getting nested accessors (`__`) and the `_gte` comparisons would be great as well.

Comment: If you could describe in more datails what is your main purpose maybe you can use `annotate` to get required data with a single SQL query. 
What can be done by your description is first query your `foos` and then filter them with Python `filter`. In that case no additional queries will be fetched. But it works only if you have no so much `foos` instances. Otherwise it will be slower.

Comment: No, `foos` is a `list` and that doesn't have the `filter()` method. Just don't change `foos` into a `list` (remove `list(...)`) so it's a `QuerySet` which you can `filter()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterable_orm library might be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/Said007/iterable_orm

Here's a (modified) example from the README:

```
from iterable_orm import QuerySet

foos = list(Foo.objects.filter(color="red"))
manager = Queryset(foos)

# Filter foos with age greater than 25 and exclude if size is large.
data = manager.filter(age__gt=20).exclude(size="large")
```

I've used it in the past and worked well for my use case.

Comment: I tried this and things ended up slower, where my problem was missing indexes on columns

Answer (score 1):

```
foos = list(Foo.objects.filter(color="red"))

large_foos = [foo for foo in foos if foo.size='large']
small_foos = [foo for foo in foos if foo.size='small']
```

It can work. But in case you have a lot of `foos` instances it could be much slower than making additional SQL query.

Comment: OP wanted to use a QuerySet-like API, not list comprehensions.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely works, just the syntax is unwieldy (e.g. if I need to filter by 2+ attributes), thus I was looking for a way to use something like the queryset api.